# Powershell regex replace line that contains ONLY certain characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I read a file with get-content **-raw** because of other operations I perform.

```
$c = get-content myfile.txt -raw
```

I want to replace the entirety of each line that contains ONLY the characters "*" or "=" with "hare"

I try

```
$c -replace "^[*=]*$","hare"
```

but that does not succeed.  It works with simple string input but not with my string that contains CRLFs.  (Other regex replace operations not involving character classes work fine.)

TEST:
given an input file of two lines

```
*=** 
keep this line ***
***=
```

The output should be

```
hare
keep this line ***
hare
```

Tried many things, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `(?m)` (`RegexOptions.Multiline`) option to make `^` match the start of a line and `$` the end of a line positions.

However, there is a caveat: the `$` anchor in a .NET regex with a multiline option matches only before a newline, LF, `` "`n" ``, char. You need to make sure an optional (or if it is always there, obligatory) CR symbol before `$`.

You may use

```
$file -replace "(?m)^[*=]*\r?$", "hare"
```

Powershell test demo:

```
PS> $file = "*=**`r`nkeep this line ***`r`n***=`r`n***==Keep this line as is"
PS> $file -replace "(?m)^[*=]*\r?$", "hare"
hare
keep this line ***
hare
***==Keep this line as is
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried multiline but the tip about CR was what I was missing .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$c = get-content "myfile.txt" -raw
$c -split [environment]::NewLine | % { if( $_ -match "^[*= ]+$" ) { "hare" } else { $_ } }
```